# Need help in lodash combinations to get the below object

Tags: javascript, lodash

Below is my object First step is to check the socialAuth array of objects and get the platformName which has the showStats value as false. 
    I have accomplished the step1 as below

```
var arrList2 = _.pluck(_.where(creatorObj.socialAuth, {'showStats': false}), "platformName");

['Twitter'] is the output of the arrList2

var creatorObj = 
{
  "_id": "55e5b32f3874c964cc3dfe2e",
  "firstName": "xyz",
  "lastName": "abc",
  "socialStats": [
    {
      "reach": 205976,
      "_id": "asdfasdfasdf",
      "profileUrl": null,
      "engagements": 126,
      "platformName": "Twitter"
    }
  ],
  "socialAuth": [
    {
      "screenName": "abc",
      "userId": "12341234",
      "_id": "55e5b3573874c964cc3dfe33",
      "showStats": false,
      "platformName": "Twitter"
    },
    {
      "channelTitle": "xyz",
      "channelId": "sdfgsdfgsdfg",
      "_id": "55e5a040991c1321a5b9bd79",
      "showStats": true,
      "platformName": "Youtube"
    }
  ]
};
```

Second step is to check the above arrList2 with the sociaStats array and remove the value from it and print the object again. 
 I need help in this second step.
I need the resulting object as

```
var creatorObj = 
{
  "_id": "55e5b32f3874c964cc3dfe2e",
  "firstName": "xyz",
  "lastName": "abc",
  "socialStats": [],
  "socialAuth": [
    {
      "screenName": "abc",
      "userId": "12341234",
      "_id": "55e5b3573874c964cc3dfe33",
      "showStats": false,
      "platformName": "Twitter"
    },
    {
      "channelTitle": "xyz",
      "channelId": "sdfgsdfgsdfg",
      "_id": "55e5a040991c1321a5b9bd79",
      "showStats": true,
      "platformName": "Youtube"
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Can you add the resulting object

Comment: @Tushar I have added the resulting object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`_.remove()`](https://lodash.com/docs#remove) to remove the elements from array based on your condition.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Lbmo8jzt/1/)

```js
var creatorObj = {
  "_id": "55e5b32f3874c964cc3dfe2e",
  "firstName": "xyz",
  "lastName": "abc",
  "socialStats": [{
    "reach": 205976,
    "_id": "asdfasdfasdf",
    "profileUrl": null,
    "engagements": 126,
    "platformName": "Twitter"
  }],
  "socialAuth": [{
    "screenName": "abc",
    "userId": "12341234",
    "_id": "55e5b3573874c964cc3dfe33",
    "showStats": false,
    "platformName": "Twitter"
  }, {
    "channelTitle": "xyz",
    "channelId": "sdfgsdfgsdfg",
    "_id": "55e5a040991c1321a5b9bd79",
    "showStats": true,
    "platformName": "Youtube"
  }]
};

var arrList2 = _.pluck(_.where(creatorObj.socialAuth, {
  'showStats': false
}), "platformName");

creatorObj.socialStats = _.remove(creatorObj.socialStats, function(n) {
  return !_.includes(arrList2, n.platformName);
});


console.log(creatorObj);
document.write(JSON.stringify(creatorObj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```